# Regex - Finding two consecutive lines only differing in case

Tags: regex

I got some input that looks like this:

Ababa
ababa
bebebe
cacaca
Dododo
dododo

How can I find the consecutive (just two consecutive ones) lines which are basically the same but just differ in the case (of the first character). For this example **[Aa]baba** & **[Dd]ododo**.

I guess it might depend on the kind of editor I use and which kind of regex it works with (I tried starting with Sublime text, case-sensitive of course):

`^([A-Z])([a-z]+)\n\l\1\2`

`\l\1` works for replacing group 1 with an initial lower case character (at least in Sublime Text), but obviously not the same when searching for such a pattern.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't `^([A-Z])([a-z]+)\n\1\2` work? Just remove `\l` and use case-insensitive search.

Comment: No, since the first group is upper case when captured but lower case after the new line. It has to be case-sensitive.

Comment: In Sublime Text, make sure `Aa` button is NOT checked and retry (disable case sensitivity).

Comment: Again, it has to be case-sensitive. I want to find lines which start upper case followed by lines with the same content but start lower case.

Comment: Aha, I see. Ok, try `^([A-Z])([a-z]+)\n(?i:\1)\2`

Comment: @user6188402: Not mine, actually, this is OP zone of responsibilty. I know nothing about what the string (=line) should consist of. Yes, a good idea.

Comment: Works like a charm, but not in Sublime Text. Do you know which regex option to use with grep (-P, -E, -G don't work) ? On regex101.com it works fine with the `pcre` style/flavor.

Comment: @user6188402, the line will only start with a upper case character or consist of only lower case ones. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems you are looking for an inline anywhere-inside-pattern case insensitive modifier `(?i:....)` around the first backreference:

```
^([A-Z])([a-z]+)\n(?i:\1)\2$
                  ^^^   ^
```

This will make the first backreference case insensitive.

To support any linebreak style, use `\R` instead of `\n`:

```
^([A-Z])([a-z]+)\R(?i:\1)\2$
                ^^
```

Boost [*Modifiers* reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html#boost_regex.syntax.perl_syntax.modifiers):

> `(?imsx-imsx ... )` alters which of the perl modifiers are in effect within the pattern, changes take effect from the point that the block is first seen and extend to any enclosing ). Letters before a `-` turn that perl modifier on, letters afterward, turn it off.

(?imsx-imsx:pattern) applies the specified modifiers to pattern only.

[image]

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of a line (in Sublime Text and Notepad++, the MUTLILINE mode is on by default)
- `([A-Z])` - (Group 1) first uppercase ASCII letter (replace `[A-Z]` with `\p{Lu}` to match any Unicode uppercase letter)
- `([a-z]+)` - (Group 2) 1 or more lowercase ASCII letters (replace `[a-z]` with `\p{Ll}` to match any Unicode lowercase letters)
- `\R` - any linebreak (`CRLF`, `LF`, or `CR`)
- `(?i:\1)` - a case-insensitive backreference to Group 1 value
- `\2` - case sensitive backreference to Group 2 value
- `$` - end of a line/file.

Comment: Oh, forget a set a flag there. That works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: The MULTILINE mode is ON by default in SublimeText and Notepad++. `^` matches the line start and `$` matches the line end. Else, you need `\A` and `\z` anchors.

Comment: This will (I think) match two consecutive lines that are identical as well. I guess that's OK.

Comment: @ChrisLear: Then, `^([A-Z])([a-z]+)\n(?!\1\2)(?i:\1)\2` should help. Or `^([A-Z])([a-z]+)\n(?!\1\2)(?i:\1)\2$`. I seem to have forgotten to check the line end. `$` must be appended, I guess.

Comment: `\R` :- hmmm...that's new to me..+1